# Search and remove with regular expression

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

How do you use regular expression in bash to search any given string and remove occurrence of particular word? This is the expression I've come up with

```
^([A-Za-z-]+)(-).*(el6.*)$
```

What I would like to accomplish is, in a given string like `cjkuni-ukai-fonts-0.2.20080216.1-35.el6.noarch`, the expression should remove `cjkuni-ukai-fonts-` and `el6.noarch`, and leave only `0.2.20080216.1-35`. As I'm very limited in what I can install on the system, I cannot use perl or other non basic commands. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S : I've tried sed, but I couldn't get it work.

Comment: What system are you running? Do you have access to GNU tools? Does your version of bash even support regular expressions?

Comment: I'm running CentOS and it does support regular expression.

Comment: And `perl` is not installed? Really?

Answer (score 5):

If you really must do it in pure bash:

```
$ foo="cjkuni-ukai-fonts-0.2.20080216.1-35.el6.noarch"
$ [[ $foo =~ [0-9.]+-[0-9]* ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
0.2.20080216.1-35
```

If you're OK with a `sed` solution:

```
$ sed 's/.*-\([0-9.]*-[0-9]*\).*/\1/' <<<$foo
0.2.20080216.1-35
```

If you have access to GNU `grep`, you could also do:

```
$ grep -oE -- '[0-9.]+-[0-9]*' <<<$foo
0.2.20080216.1-35
```

or

```
$ grep -oP -- '[.\d]+-\d+' <<<$foo
0.2.20080216.1-35
```

Finally, since you're running a CentOS system, it is a fairly safe bet that Perl is installed, so you could also do:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?([0-9.]+-[0-9]*).*/$1/' <<<$foo
0.2.20080216.1-35
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP means by "I cannot use Perl", PCRE support for `grep` may not be available. This shouldn't be the case on a standard CentOS install, though...

Comment: @JosephR. I know, that's why I clarified that it needs GNU `grep`. You need that for `-o` anyway, let alone the PCREs. No idea what makes the OP thing that `perl` itself is not installed by default on CentOS. Perhaps it's an _extremely_ minimalist setup.